# create new column with data in a column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

So here is my data in pandas

```
      Movie        Tags
0  War film  tank;plane
1  Spy film   car;plane
```

i would like to create new column with the tag column with 0 and 1  and add a prefix like 'T_' to the name of the columns.

Like :

```
      Movie        Tags T_tank T_plane T_car
0  War film  tank;plane      1       1     0
1  Spy film   car;plane      0       1     1
```

I have some ideas on how to do it like line by line with a split(";") and a df.loc[:,'T_plane'] for example.
But i think that may not be the optimal way to do it.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.str.get_dummies`

```
df.join(df.Tags.str.get_dummies(';').add_prefix('T_'))

      Movie        Tags  T_car  T_plane  T_tank
0  War film  tank;plane      0        1       1
1  Spy film   car;plane      1        1       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `sklearn` library:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

res = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Tags'].str.split(';')),
                           columns=mlb.classes_).add_prefix('T_'))

print(res)

      Movie        Tags  T_car  T_plane  T_tank
0  War film  tank;plane      0        1       1
1  Spy film   car;plane      1        1       0
```